# How to customize joomla default Pagination HTML

Tags: php, joomla, pagination, joomla2.5

I have joomla module that prints the pagination in page.
I've used

```
$pagination = new JPagination($total, $p_start, 2);
echo $pagination->getPagesLinks();
echo $pagination->getPagesCounter();
```

and it will correctly print the pagination. But I want to change that printing `HTML` to match my design. Default design is just `ul` `li` tags.
 How do I change that without editing core library files?
I'm using `joomla 2.5`

Thanks.

Comment: try overriding template css file

Answer (score 3):

You need to override pagination class in your template, please check this link for more info: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides